# Early 90s sci-fi movie very similar to Star Wars with lightsabers and laser guns

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, movie

I saw a movie in the early 90's, it was sci-fi but I can't find the name.

Here are a few points I know for sure:

1. It's VERY *Star Wars* like. Yes, the movie has lightsabers and laser guns, but it's almost like it's an episode from a Star Wars series because I'm 80% sure that I actually saw Darth Vader in the movie, and here's the scene with Darth Vader I remember the best:

   There is a hallway with a red carpet. Everything is beautiful and futuristic, like maybe the walls are golden, and there's a lot of guards all through the hall. They have their backs to the wall, they're not moving, and all of them are dressed the same way, all in red. I think they are holding a futuristic staff or some sort. Darth Vader passes between them as they are staring face-to-face, one next to each other, like soldiers.
2. Another scene I remember is at the end of the movie/episode, someone who looks like Luke is fighting Vader on what seems to be a floating platform. And there's laser beams from guns coming everywhere as if they were battling in the middle of a war.
3. Another scene that marked me, I remember seeing a creature imprisoned behind bars, and I think she is on the good side but at the same time she is horrible.

That's all I remember, but like I said I'm 100% sure it's linked somehow to *Star Wars* universe, and I would be so grateful guys if any one of you can help me on this!

Ok so it was not *Yor, the Hunter from the Future*. And I watched *Masters of the Universe*, and it's crazy how close it was; I mean I felt like maybe it was it. But after watching it, it was clear that it's not the movie I'm looking for, even though it's the closest so far I've seen.

There's a scene in my movie, where I remember clearly watching like jail bars, and the hands of some creature begging through it, idious hands if my memory is good.

And the final battle I'm 100% sure was with lightsabers, straight out of a *Star Wars* movie, and I know it may sound wack but I really think that the final battle on the black platform was looking like Vader.

Thanks for all the suggestions. It's really important still today for me to figure out what that movie was!

Comment: Are you entirely sure it's not one of the Star Wars films? http://www.empireonline.com/images/uploaded/greatest-star-wars-characters-imperial-guards.jpg

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hqcGK72XYQ?

Comment: LOL, wow! That was terrible!

Comment: I think for #3 you might be remembering the sci-fi parody *Galaxina*, currently available on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLn3y4GMCBA)...see the scene starting at 15:10 where a prison guard visits a monster named "Rock Eater" in the brig (starts out dark but they turn the lights up at 15:25)--the character does sound like it was voiced by a woman. I haven't watched the whole thing, but jumping through it quickly I don't see scenes to match #1 and #2, could it be you're mixing up memories of different films, possibly including Richard's suggestion of *Starcrash*?

Comment: I paid actual *money* to see *Galaxina* in the theater when it came out. That's 95 minutes of my life I'd like to have back, please.

Comment: I'm going to suggest **Starcrash** an Italian/American production that came out around this time. It certainly has lightsaber like weapons and has David Hasselhoff in it.

Comment: Maybe [Starcrash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starcrash)"? It has "light sabers", "laser guns" and a Jedi-like character played by - wait for it - David Hasselhoff. It's much older than the '90s and I don't remember the plot details other than it was a B-movie Star War-sy plot. Was that also the movie with the "fist-shaped" space weapon/station/ship?

Comment: "the final battle on the black platform was looking like Vader" — it's not clear what you're trying to say here. Was there a character involved in then final battle who looked like Darth Vader?

Answer (score 14):

It wasn't Flash Gordon was it?  Any of these shots jog your memory?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Could you be thinking of [Masters of the Universe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093507/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (the He-Man movie)?  The film was released in 1987.

1. In one of the opening scenes, Skeletor walks down the hall of Castle Greyskull with guards on either side of him.  He is holding a staff that he strikes on the floor as he walks. (It is a very memorable scene)
2. Near the end of the movie, He-Man battles Skeletor on top of a floating platform during the final battle.
3. The Sorceress is the good character that Skeletor has imprisoned in the castle. He is stealing her power, and she gets older and more deformed as her power is stolen.

There are lots of lasers and other sci-fi weapons, exciting battles, etc. in this movie.

[image: Skeletor in his throne room]

[image: Sorceress]

[image: He-Man, Man-At-Arms, Teela, and Gwildor]

Comment: Good call! That matches up pretty nicely.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what your describing is the movie Spaceballs from 1987. You said you saw it in the early 90's so that would make sense. This movie is a parody of Star Wars. In this movie, there is a villain called Dark Helmet, who is supposed to represent Darth Vader and the character Captain Lone Starr who is kind of a like a mix between Han Solo and Luke Skywalker. They fight using lightsabers that come out of these rings called Schwartz rings (Schwartz is essentially the force which is channeled through a ring.) If someone wants to edit this to add videos of the described scenes feel free, I don't have the time to do so. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you remember a horrible prisoner, probably female and good-aligned? That was one of the criteria mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately no, and based on some research I cant find anything that would suggest that particular part is in Spaceballs. I know there's a scene that resembles Alien in it, in where an Alien creature comes out of a guys stomach then precedes to tap dance, but thats all I can find.

Comment: You could be right: the prisoner would be Princess Vespa. She was a stereotypical "Jewish princess"; vain and nasty to talk to. However, she was not a creature and didn't beg through the bars.

Answer (score 4):

A very early Star Wars rip-off was [Yor: Hunter from the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yor,_the_Hunter_from_the_Future). It is a stretch, but it does have some Darth Vader clones and lots of laser weapons.  It is pre-1990, so it fits the time frame. I acknowledge this is a stretch.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be '[Star Crash](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/)'? No Darth Vader but definitely a Star Wars rip-off. However, this movie is from 1978 so it pre-dates you '90's' estimate. Also, featured in MST3K on Neflix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since it's one of the criteria people have been pointing out for other answers, is there a case with a horrific female prisoner begging through the bars?

Comment: and the best(?): its featuring "david hasselhoff" (known from knight rider).